# Using Nori and Prawn

Tags: ruby, xml, prawn

I recently started using Prawn in my application to generate PDFs, I also use Nori to parse XML and send SMS.

I realized that my app couldnt send SMS anymore, I got this error message:

```
nori:  undefined method `closed?' for # < Hash:0xb0320e0>

/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:109:in `close'
/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@portal/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:66:in `ensure in execute'
/ruby-1.9.3-p194@portal/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:66:in `execute'
```

It fails in these line (request is built with `RestClient::Request.new`):

```
Nori.parse(request.execute)
```

If I comment Prawn in my Gemfile it works again, and it works if I use Prawn 0.8.4 but I need Prawn methods from newer versions. I couldnt find anything on internet referring to incompatibilities between these two gems. Can anyone could tell me what's going wrong and how to solve it?

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
gem "prawn", "~> 0.12.0"

gem "nori",  "~>1.1.3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem finally.
Adding Prawn to my Gemfile caused RestClient to stop working because one of its dependencies, pdf-reader 1.2.0.
I had to change its version to pdf-reader 1.1.1 in the Gemfile.lock and it worked fine again.